# Trouble validating input in Person class

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, input, do-while

I'm writing a program for a school assignment where I create a sports competition.
In the method for creating a participant we're supposed to perform some input validation (can't be null or empty). But I can't get it to work. I'm saving the participant in an ArrayList and the participant shall have a `firstname`, `lastname` and belong to a team.

I've tried numerous solution here on stackoverflow, but none seem to work. 
At the moment I use an if-else:

```
    Participant ParticipantArr = new Participant();

    String firstNameType = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Firstname: ");
    ParticipantArr.setFirstName(firstNameType);
```

In Participant.java:

```
        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {

    if (firstName == null || firstName.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("The name is incorrect");
    } else {
        this.firstName = firstName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + firstName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

I've also tried a do-while with the same Participant class:

```
    String firstNameType;
    do  {
        System.out.print("Firstname: ");
        firstNameType = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (firstNameType.trim().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("The name cannot be empty!");

        }
    } while (firstNameType.isEmpty() || firstNameType == null);
    ParticipantArr.setFirstName(firstNameType);
```

I've tried changing `firstNameType == null` to `.equals(null)`, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Edit: sorry, the program just adds "null" to the arraylist as an object or I can spam space/enter until a word is entered. Which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: What does "I can't get it to work" mean, *precisely*?

Comment: What is the result you get and what is the result you want.

Comment: Also show us an [mcve]

Comment: @Jens sorry, the program just adds "null" to the arraylist as an object or I can spam space/enter until a word is entered. Which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Hint use a debugger to find out what is happend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
firstNameType = keyboard.nextLine();
if (firstNameType.trim().isEmpty()) {
```

*when* nextLine() returns null, this must lead to a NullPointerException.

My suggestion: do something like:

In your Participant class, you add:

```
public static boolean isValidFirstName(String name) {
  if (name == null || name.isEmpty() || name.trim().isEmpty()) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

and call that from your within your loop! In other words: have your validation code in **one central** place; instead of copying all over the place.

For your actual problem; hard to say; but in general, when using a Scanner, those class has a whole set of methods like [hasNextLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine()) that can be used to **check** that there is really some input available!

Edit; a more complete solution could look like:

```
String firstNameType = null;
do  {
    System.out.print("Please enter first name: ");
    firstName = keyboard.nextLine();
  } while (! Participant.isValidFirstName(firstName) )
```

In other words: just keep your user entering new names; until there is one that is accepted!

Comment: It did help with isEmpty(); can you force a NullPointerException to try it out?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - the point is: you can *always* write **test** methods to *test* your "production" code; for example using JUnit. In your current case; I *think* that this call to keyboard.nextLine() should normally not return null, but well, we **dont know** what class that really, and what is going, as your overall input isn't covering those aspects.

Comment: You are very welcome; and feel free to show your gratitude by just remembering about this answer; so one day, when you reach upvote rights, to come back and upvote, too ;-)